# How can I solve inflating class error at Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to add payment from for my application. I use that [library](https://github.com/fevziomurtekin/PayView) for that. I added it to my project. I'm also try delete from gradle and re-install it but it gave same error again.

**Here my xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OdemeSayfasi">


    <com.fevziomurtekin.payview.Payview
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/payview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**In run time I got error which is:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.slidework3, PID: 23708
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slidework3/com.example.slidework3.OdemeSayfasi}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.fevziomurtekin.payview.Payview
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.fevziomurtekin.payview.Payview
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.slidework3.OdemeSayfasi.onCreate(OdemeSayfasi.kt:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This error is very long so I get only first parts of it.

How can I solve it? I try to inflate layout but I can't solve it. I'm waiting for your advices and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate it and noticed this message alongside with what you have shown:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

The reason being the [library uses MDC](https://github.com/fevziomurtekin/PayView/blob/fc13162f0b8b94f3757882195165ac02ecd4210a/payview/src/main/res/layout/payview_layout.xml#L240).
I had to change the existing app theme applied into Material Design Component(MDC) based, so to make avoid the error; Example: In under `style.xml`:

`<style name="AppTheme"parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">`

**Edit:** If you don't want to affect the apptheme, you can just apply a Material Component theme to just the `payview`.

```
<com.fevziomurtekin.payview.Payview
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/payview"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"/>
```

If you want to customise your payview, just create a  custom theme whose parent based on  Theme.MaterialComponents .

Comment: I did it but my application buttons or another drawable customizations changed too. Is there any way to avaoid this?

Comment: And also NoActionBar give null pointer exception, DarkActionBar working but everything look different

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look at it.